# if I record video on my 720p screen I can get a video with 1080p?

Tags: display, video

I have a screen with 720p.
I want to know if I can screen my pc and the video I get will be 1080p for example ?!

Comment: If you're asking whether you can record your desktop screen at 1080p using screen recorder software, then no you can't. The software will record at whatever the current desktop resolution is. However if your graphics card is capable of setting the screen resolution to 1080p, then I think it could be possible.

Comment: @Vinayak this is the answer I search make it as an answer if you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking whether you can record the desktop screen at 1080p resolution using screen recorder software, then the answer is no, you can't.

The software usually will record at whatever the current desktop screen resolution is (which you can lower). However if your graphics card is capable of setting the screen resolution to 1080p, then I think it could be possible, however I haven't tried this out, so I'm not sure about this.

Answer (score 0):

No the video from using a screen recorder can be at maximum your screen resolution for the ones I know. I suspect there is probably a way but most screen recorders try to make the video recorded look exactly like the one you see.

Answer (score 0):

If you watch a 1080p video (or a 1080i video, for that matter) on a computer with a 720p screen, one of several things can happen:

1. the video will be downscaled to 720p. You'll be able to watch it but it will be at 720p resolution. This is the default behavior if your video player is set to take up the entire screen.
2. the video will be shown at 1080 lines, but parts of the scene will not be visible as they will spill off the sides of your screen. If you click and drag the display window you'll be able to see the other parts, but not the whole thing at once.
3. you can actually resize most video player apps' windows so you can watch at almost any res you want.

Comment: Thank you for the knowledge :) , but my question is about recording screen not watching a 1080p video ! :)

Comment: Ah. You might mention the word "record" next time :)

Comment: If you're using "screen scraping" software, this still provides the answer: Your screen scraper is only going to scrape the pixels that are on your screen; the fact that the source had more pixels will be lost by the time it gets to the screen. But if you use tools that capture the _stream_, then you aren't limited by your local screen size.

Answer (score 0):

There is another alternative: Ubuntu has an **xrandr** utility which allows you to set almost any desktop size you want: your terminal screen becomes a panning window into this virtual desktop. It is an X-windows function, so most Linux releases should have it.

I have successfully used this technique to capture higher-resolution images from web-sites, for example when I want to screen-capture a whole web-page which needs scrolling on a normal desktop. The only limitation seems to be that you need more RAM for a larger desktop.

Whether you can perform the actions you want to record on a windowed desktop is another matter.